# Rcpp CharacterVector: why aren't individual elements std::strings?

Tags: string, r, rcpp

this might be a stupid question but i thought that each individual element of a `CharacterVector` would be a `std::string`. However, this doesnt work:

```
std::string hello(CharacterVector vec) {
   std::string result = vec[0];
   return result;
}
```

Error: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Proxy' (aka 'string_proxy<16>') to 'const_pointer' (aka 'const char *') for 1st argument

If so should we force a conversion to `std::string` before we get the C++ goodies like `empty()`, etc?

Comment: FWIW, the conversion has been added to Rcpp11. Closing the [related issue](https://github.com/Rcpp11/Rcpp11/issues/152).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes you need to help the compiler.

The converter `Rcpp::as<T>()` converts *from* R, the converter `Rcpp::wrap()` converts *to* R.

```
R> cppFunction('std::string hello(CharacterVector vec) { 
                                return as<std::string>(vec[0]); }')
R> hello(c("The", "quick", "brown", "fox"))
[1] "The"
R>
```

This is all documented, and there are copious examples.  It may well be possible to  find smarter template programming to automate this conversion too, and if so we'd love to see a patch.

For the second part of your question: these come from R, and does not know or have `std::string`.  We have lightweight wrapper classes which generally avoid copying. Hence `Rcpp::CharacterVector` -- which you can convert to `std::vector<std::string>`.

*Edit late 2016:*  Note that we can also do

```
R> cppFunction("std::string f(CharacterVector x,int i) {return std::string(x[i]);}")
R> foo(c("The", "quick", "brown", "fox"), 1)
[1] "quick"
R>
```

Comment: i see. is the drawback of conversion that there is copying involved, and therefore it becomes less memory efficient?

Comment: also, i googled around and went through the first 2 pages of results, but no example answered this question directly. could you please point me in the direction of the examples? i'm interested in learning more about how the templating works. i'm far from a patch but would love to help out in any way i can! :D

Comment: Copying has a cost in terms of memory and execution.  If you want to write yourself different extractors to `std::string`, you should find examples in our code and tests.